# Pandas Dataframe has no Plot function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plot

I'm trying to call `df.plot.scatter(...)` as shown [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#scatter-plot), where `df` is a `pandas.Dataframe` object.

But my IDE can't suggest any plot function when I initiate suggestions (though it can suggest other `dataframe` members like `fillna()`, `to_json()` etc).

If I anyway write `df.plot.scatter(...)` and run it, it gives error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'scatter'
```

I use python 3.4 on windows 7. My IDE is PyCharm. These are the imports:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Can it be about my python version, or maybe this function is removed from pandas API? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add your code please?

Comment: What is version of your `pandas`? Check it by `pd.show_versions()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your `pandas` version is older as `0.17.0`.

See [`DataFrame.plot.scatter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html):

> New in version 0.17.0.

In older version you can use:

```
df.plot(kind='scatter')
```